# Linq query performance between C# and LINQPad

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, linqpad

In my Application is use this linq query :

```
var r = from uev in UtilisateurEpisodeVus
        group uev by uev.Episode.Saison.Serie into pgroup
        let count = pgroup.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new SerieVu() { nombreDeVus = count, Serie = pgroup.Key };
return r.ToList();
```

In LINQPad is use approximately the same query using the same connection with Entity Framework:

```
from uev in UtilisateurEpisodeVus
group uev by uev.Episode.Saison.Serie into pgroup
let count = pgroup.Count()
orderby count descending
select pgroup.Key
```

In my application the:

```
resultat.ToList()
```

take about 45 seconds.

In LINQPad it take 191 milliseconds.

What is the problem please?

Comment: Compare the SQL generated by EF using SQL Profiler for your application (or the Log property on your context) and the SQL Tab in Linqpad. You will probably see some differences.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your help I have found the solution using Entity Framework Profiler trial.. In fact I was doing this :

```
IEnumerable<UtilisateurEpisodeVu>   listUtilisateurEpisodeVu = Query(uev => uev.userepivu_date > dateIlYaSeptJours);

var resultat =
from uev in listUtilisateurEpisodeVu
group uev by uev.Episode.Saison.Serie into pgroup
let count = pgroup.Count()
orderby count descending
select new SerieVu() { nombreDeVus = count, Serie = pgroup.Key };
```

And by doing :

```
var resultat =
from uev in Query(uev => uev.userepivu_date > dateIlYaSeptJours)
group uev by uev.Episode.Saison.Serie into pgroup
let count = pgroup.Count()
orderby count descending
select new SerieVu() { nombreDeVus = count, Serie = pgroup.Key };
```

using Query directly in my linq query the performance is great... I don't understand why. If someone have any idea, i will be glad to know the answer. Thanks again

Comment: Now I know why: My Query method return a IQueryable interface and using it without converting results to IEnumerable avoid a database call. Performance are the same if I replace IEnumerable<UtilisateurEpisodeVu> by IQueryable<UtilisateurEpisodeVu>. Hope it help

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
IEnumerable<UtilisateurEpisodeVu>   listUtilisateurEpisodeVu
from uev in listUtilisateurEpisodeVu
group uev
```

You are grouping an `IEnumerable<T>`, which turns into a call on `System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy`, which loads the whole table and executes locally.

---

When you say

```
from uev in Query(uev => uev.userepivu_date > dateIlYaSeptJours)
group uev
```

You are grouping an `IQueryable<T>`, which turns into a call on `System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy`, which is translated into sql and sent to the database.

You can get the same result by changing the type of the variable:

```
IQueryable<UtilisateurEpisodeVu>   listUtilisateurEpisodeVu
from uev in listUtilisateurEpisodeVu
group uev
```